# Angular 2 Observable skip until returned arrays length > 0

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2

As the title says I am trying to keep skipping within the subscription until the returned arrays length is > 0.

Currently I am trying the following but getting an empty [] back

```
let sub = this.subscribeUserByUsername(post.username).take(1)
     .subscribe(x =>
        {

          console.log('post username: ', post.username); // works
          console.log(x); // shows empty array
            try {
                  if(x[0].uid !== '' && x[0].uid !== undefined && x[0].uid !== null) {
                    // complete
                  }  catch (ex){ 

                  }
                  finally {  sub.unsubscribe(); }
        });
```

I have seen some other methods like:
.skip
.skipUntil
etc

But I am unsure of what is the best way to do this?
I need to kill the subscription when it is finished to prevent duplicate data popping up.

I can see the returned array working if I just leave the subscription running but I want to kill the sub when it returns an array with a length of greater than 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`skipWhile`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/skipwhile.md):

```
let sub = this.subscribeUserByUsername(post.username)
  .skipWhile(v => v.length === 0)
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(<your-handler>)
```

It is important that the `.take(1)` comes after the `skipWhile` so you want unsubscribe prematurely.